# How to detect the state of a Webelement if only it's colour changes

Tags: ios, webdriver, automated-tests, appium

My problem is this: 
I have an application and I have to decide the state of an element. The element can have two states, in position number 1 - it has black background in position number 2 - it has white background. Nothing else changes on it, nor it's size, nor it's value, nor it's name, nor it's visibility, nor it's enabled value nothing... Only it's background colour.

Imagine it like if you had a button on the screen and tapping on it changes only it's background.

Do you have any idea what could I do in order to get the state of this webelement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly , you want to identify the element with its background color. You can do that with [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/) Java api

The easiest way is Option 2 under "How do I set up SikuliX"  and [here](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/wiki/Usage-in-Java-programming) is how to use it with Java (with Maven, so you have all the dependencies)

[here](https://github.com/mygithub07/automation-java-sikuliX) is a project I did with SikuliX, in case it is of any help.

I am not sure , if you are trying to do it in mobile but I think right now it can not be used with mobile devices, as mentioned in pre-requisites.